# Strange assignment mechanism with the walrus operator

Tags: python-3.x

As we know, integers are singletones for values in [-5...256], but

```py
>>>(id(q:=-6) == id(q2:=-6) , id(w:=0) == id(w1:=0), id(e:=600) == id(e1:=600))
(False, True, True)
```

If we try assing variables without walrus:

```py
>>>e = 600
>>>e1 = 600
>>>id(e) == id(e1)
False
>>>id(e), id(e1)
(1813997325616, 1813997325040)
```

Can you explain this behavior?

Comment: I think there is some kind of optimization. Within the same construction, positive and negative literals are singletons, but if the assignment constructs separate - the literals cease to be singleton.

Comment: What is stranger, with walrus it works for all positive numbers, and for negative numbers only in the case of `[0...-5]` real singletons